# Почему нельзя использовать static переменные в сервисе

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-intent, static

Недавно задавала вопрос про сервис и в комментах писала что создаю в сервисе `static` переменные и передаю из активити в сервис данные так

Это статичные переменные сервиса

```
static String url;
static String title;
```

А это как я передаю в них данные из активити

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Second.this, MyService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.url, url);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.title, title);
```

Мне один из участников написал что нежелательно использовать статичные переменные потому что неизвестно что будет в этих переменных после уничтожения сервиса..

Сейчас на просторах интернета нашла пример, где используются статичные переменные http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html

Скажите пожалуйста что в этом плохого, если я также буду использовать статичные переменные для своего онлайн плеера?  Объясните на пальчиках почему нежелательно использовать)

В сервисе

```
    String url;
    String title;

    public static final String KEY_URL = MyService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_URL";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = MyService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_TITLE";



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
    this.radio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RADIO);


    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

в активити

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Second.this, MyService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.KEY_URL, url);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.KEY_TITLE, title);
```

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/should-you-avoid-or-embrace-static/) очень исчерпывающе рассказано

Comment: просто скажите для начала так можно или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/should-you-avoid-or-embrace-static/) очень исчерпывающе написано про `static`.

Вы немного не правильно поняли принцип работы метода `putExtra(String, Object)`.
Первым параметром для него служит строковый идентификатор (метка) для хранения  внутри `intent`'a объекта, который передаётся вторым параметром. Эта метка необходима для того чтобы в вашем случае, в методе `onStartCommand` Вашего сервиса, Вы могли достать из `intent`'a необходимые данные. **Он НЕ кладёт значение второго параметра в первую переменную.** Так как обе переменные у вас равны `null`, то достать ничего не получится.

Для передачи данных в сервис через интент можно сделать следущее:

**Создать 2 публичных поля-метки внутри Вашего сервиса:**

```
public static final String KEY_URL = MyService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_URL"; 
public static final String KEY_TITLE = MyService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_TITLE";
```

**Использовать эти константы при создании интента:**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Second.this, MyService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.KEY_URL, url); 
serviceIntent.putExtra(MyService.KEY_TITLE, title);
```

**Затем использовать их же для вытаскивания данных из интента (в сервисе):**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.url = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_URL);
    this.title = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

---

**UPD**

Для передачи данных типа `int` используются данные методы:

```
serviceIntent.putExtra(String, int); //сеттер (кладём данные)
serviceIntent.getIntExtra(String, int); //геттер (берем данные)
```

В случае геттера второй параметр служит дефолтным значением и будет использован если значение по данному ключу не будет найдено.

---

Все возможные методы `intent`'a можно найти в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Т.е. если я правильно поняла первый параметр  является своего рода ключом через который передается второй параметр.. Если согласно вашему примеру переделаю код у себя в сервисе и в активити, то будет все корректно работать и не получится так что в сервисе вдруг url или title окажутся пустыми?

Comment: @Наталья_MI Да, именно так

Comment: А что за метод getSimpleName() в вашем примере?

Comment: @Наталья_MI Этот метод возвращает имя класса. Его рекомендуется использовать если в проекте нет классов с одинаковым именем. Если вы переименуете класс посредством `shift` + `f6` (РКМ → refactor → rename) префиксы значений констант останутся актуальными.

Comment: А поняла т.е. это стандартный метод, я то думала пользовательский метод. Спасибо за ответ. Теперь поняла как передавать и получать данные в сервисе

Comment: У меня такой метод intent.getString(KEY_URL); не находит. Есть getStringExtra()

Comment: @Наталья_MI Да, прошу прощения, обновил ответ

Comment: Я в вопрос добавила что у меня получилось, посмотрите пожалуйста. И еще как передать целое число таким же образом из активити в сервис? У меня компилятор ругался требовал строковый тип

Comment: @Наталья_MI обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Пойду против общественного мнения, сказав, что `static` переменные в сервисе использовать **можно** и иногда даже **нужно**. Вам, как программисту, дается инструмент, а что с ним делать - *решаете вы*, именно за это программистам платят деньги. Но это лишь инструмент, как и при помощи молотка, им можно причинить себе боль, особенно если не уметь пользоваться.

Краткий перевод статьи, упомянутой выше: https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/should-you-avoid-or-embrace-static/ - какой-то преподаватель, уставший от своих служебных обязанностей, замучался рассказывать своим студентам о статик методах и полях и решил исключить их из своего курса, посчитав, что так ему будет проще. А автор предупреждает, что в ваш проект могут придти некомпетентные люди и все сломают, но виноваты в этом будут, конечно же, статик-методы и поля. Скопирую заключение: Cutting a long story short, I consider static variables dangerous, static methods useful and static classes sort of superfluous - и никакого криминала тут нет.

В общем, изучайте тот инструмент, который используете, даже если он выглядит совсем простым. И конечно же, инициализируйте переменные сами, проверяйте их значения. Используйте звание программиста и свою голову не для того, чтобы попивая пивко в подъезде, гордиться зарплатой, а для достижения реальных целей.